# Fragment Menuitem Click

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragement, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.color_menu:
            intent.setClass(rootView.getContext(), CandleColorActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,COLOR_ACTION);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Using the above code menu item is visible in the fragment but item click is not working. Menu item xml:

```
<item
android:title="selectColor"
android:icon="@drawable/addcolor"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:id="@+id/color_menu"></item>
```

main activity menu xml always show on each of the fragment

```
<item
android:title="menu"
android:icon="@drawable/menu"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:id="@+id/uper_menu"></item>
```

Main activity menu java code open a dialog box on the item click

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.uper_menu:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(R.layout.menu_dialog);
            alertDialog = builder.show();

            alertDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            viewIds();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is the above code written in the Fragment or Activity?

Comment: its in the fragment

Comment: Add a `Log` inside the case and check if you are getting the log.

Comment: Does the containing activity also have a menu?

Comment: yes, its also have a menu.

Comment: please also add code activity's menu related code and the xml of the activity's menu.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: see updated answer. I think it's because you always return true in activity.

Comment: it's working. Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer below as correct, so others having the same problem will know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call the super class' `onOptionsItemSelected()`, if you handled the event yourself. So change your method to this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.color_menu:
            ...
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }           
}
```

**EDIT**

In fragment and activity, only return true, if you handled the event, otherwise return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

Reason is, that the system first asks the activity to handle the event, and if the activity says it did handle it (by returning true), the system doesn't ask the fragment anymore.

Comment: try setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the method to see if it is called.

Comment: I already did. Its go to main activity menu not working for a fragment menu

Comment: And you did `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the fragment's `onCreate()`, right?